# Softwares for analyzing MPEG4 and H264 streams

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-processing

Can someone provide names of good software that are used for analyzing MPEG4 and H264 streams.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Elecard stereameye its really good. They have evaluation version with can analyze 200 frames which can be enough for most of the development work.
It can show MBType, Transform type, slices , bits stats, entire MB, frame,level data.

Other then that you can also use JM decoder in debug mode, it prints out lots of information but its text only :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a commercial suite, this is one of the best, from [tektronix](http://www.tek.com/Measurement/video_audio/mts4ea/)

If you are a bit more specific in your question, it's easier to tailor the answer towards your specific needs...

Comment: I have PTZ networks cameras. I captured their video streams using my own APIs developed in C. I want to verify the Frames, Frames rate etc in Video stream that I captured.

Comment: If that's all you need, you don't need a stream analyzer. Just open the file in a good video player and it'll tell you.